# Are there any Pokestops that are "out of bounds"

Tags: pokemon-go

I wonder, are there any Pokestops that have invalid/glitched/bugged locations or are "out of bounds"? By "out of bounds" I mean either stuff that aren't in the playable map, or if put onto, say, Google Maps, would show up as if they were somehow below the South Pole or above the North Pole.

Comment: Recalling from my days as an Ingress agent, the Niantic games think in [S2](https://s2geometry.io/) coordinates, so being "above the North Pole" isn't even a concept that can be represented.

Answer (score 6):

Over the years there have been many glitched waypoints that end up at [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island), but that's not out of bounds, just somewhere no-one would ever (legitimately) be playing at. These have been cleaned up though, and the only waypoints that remain at Null Island are 10 Field Trip waypoints imported from Architizer, none of which are visible in Pokémon Go.

It is likely impossible for any waypoint to be "out of bounds", but there's no real way of knowing if there's any junk data in the database. Certainly there's no out of bounds waypoint visible via any ordinary means (in-game, via the Mission authoring tool, on Intel, or in Campfire).

Answer (score 1):

Over the years, I have known about glitched waypoints, but there is no "Out of bounds" zone. As a friend at Niantic told me, only WiFi-less areas are basically out of bounds since you can't play in those areas. As I don't have access to the Niantic code, I must assume. As the whole point of Pokemon Go is to have fun, it would be foolish to at out of bounds zone, but @Sellyme said, it would be unlikely for any waypoint to be out of bounds.